# MarkLogic patch and namespace prefixes

Tags: marklogic

Is there a way to force MarkLogic patch to keep prefixes when the provided fragment uses them? The [documentation for rapi:insert](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/documents#id_50902) says "When inserting elements, text, comments, and processing directives, specify the new nodes as they should appear in the target document," but it doesn't always keep prefixes and I don't see a way to tell it to.

Applying this patch:

```
<rapi:patch xmlns:rapi="http://marklogic.com/rest-api"
    xmlns:t1="http://test.com/test1" xmlns:t2="http://test.com/test2">
    <rapi:insert context="/t1:one" position="last-child">
        <t2:two t2:prefixed-attribute="foo">stuff</t2:two>
    </rapi:insert>
</rapi:patch>
```

to this document:

```
<t1:one xmlns:t1="http://test.com/test1"/>
```

results in:

```
<t1:one xmlns:t1="http://test.com/test1">
    <two t2:prefixed-attribute="foo" xmlns="http://test.com/test2"
        xmlns:t2="http://test.com/test2">stuff</two>
</t1:one>
```

While this is valid XML, it's an odd way of doing it, and the reason I care is that it's causing problems with some downstream processing that apparently doesn't expect both of these declarations on a node.

If the parent `t1:one` node has `xmlns:t2` declared, then it works as desired, but the data I'm working with doesn't (and shouldn't) always have that. I also tried to declare `xmlns:t2` on the inserted node in the patch, but it didn't help.

Using MarkLogic version 9.0-1.1.

Comment: Given that the XML is valid, maybe the best approach is to improve the downstream processing.  To put it another way, it's best to depend on the parsed XML model instead of a particular serialization of XML.

Comment: Looking there too... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977427/attributes-with-namespaces-in-jaxb-any-element